# Subscript out of range assigning new Chart values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write some VBA code to scroll through a chart with date on the x-axis. Each press of the button should change the displayed data forward by one week.

When I run the code, it gives me a Subscript out of range error on this line:

```
With Charts("Chart 1").Axes(xlValue)
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub ForwardButtonClick()

Range("CurrentDate").Value = Range("CurrentDate").Value + 7

With Charts("Chart 1").Axes(xlValue)
 .MinimumScale = Range("CurrentDate").Value
 .MaximumScale = Range("CurrentDate").Value + 7
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the chart on a chart sheet, or on a regular worksheet ?

Comment: The chart is on a regular worksheet.

Comment: Then try `With ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Axes(xlValue)`

Comment: Hmm. What you wrote did not work, but if I use `With Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Axes(xlValue)`, it works. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: `ChartObjects` does not exist in the global VBA scope.  It applies only to a `Worksheet` object.  Some `Worksheet` variables have been brought out into the global scope for the `ActiveSheet` (e.g. `Range`, `Cells`, etc.) but most have not (e.g. `UsedRange`, `ChartObjects`, and most others) and need the worksheet referenced first.

Answer (score 0):

The value `xlValue` refers to the Value axis - or the Y axis.

If you're trying to change the X axis, you need to use `xlCategory`.